# Sudden degradation of network file-transfer rate

Tags: networking, jcifs

I've been using jcifs-1.3.17 for over a year now, transferring thousands of files from place A to place B, without problems. The file transfers have always taken from 15-30ms. Yesterday (7/13/16) something changed and the transfers are now taking about 90seconds - not milliseconds, but seconds. I can identify a 15-minute window in which the change happened. Operations insists that nothing in the network or on the servers changed. My code code didn't change, nor the character/size of the files.

Has anyone else experienced something like this? Any ideas on what I might look at to determine root cause?

Comment: I should note: file transfers are from Windows Server 2012 to a share on Windows Server 2008 R2

Comment: I think it's more appropriate to ask questions like this on https://superuser.com . Anyway, first check if the transfer occurs during the whole 90 seconds period, or if it only effectively occur on the last few miliseconds of the 90 second period and update your question with that info.

Comment: ok. I didn't know about superuser.com. Unfortunately, we didn't get metrics on the distribution of transfer over the 90 secs... and now things are working at normal speed again.